# Clarification: Closed subsets of a subset of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let's say we have a metric space $(X,d)$, and a closed subset $A \subseteq X$.

What does it exactly mean to say that $F$ is a closed subset of $A$?

I'm thinking it means either:

1. $\mathrm{closure(F)} = F\ $ AND $\ F\subseteq A$.
2. $F$ is a closed subset in the metric space $(A,\widetilde{d})$ (where $\widetilde{d}$ is the restriction of $d$ to $A$)

Is it one of these two options? Is it possible both are equivilent? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A$ is closed, the two definitions you gave are equivalent.

If $A$ was any subset, to say that $F$ is a closed subset of $A$ means that $F$ is a subset of $A$, and that $F$ is closed in the subspace topology of $A$ (i.e. that $F$ can be realized as the intersection of a closed set in $X$ with $A$).